# Django Form not rendering - following documentation

Tags: python, django, forms

I am following:
I have built a project from following the general tutorial on the same site.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django
I have created this forms.py and placed it in my apps folder (polls).

My polls/templates/polls/index.html:

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The page shows the button "Submit", but no input field.

My polls/views.py:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
   template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'


def get_name(request):
           ... As in the link
```

polls/forms.py:
    from django import forms

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    print("NAMEFORM NAMEFORM NAMEFORM")
    your_name = forms.CharField(label="Your name", max_length = 100)
    age = forms.IntegerField(label="Your age")
```

All I see is the "Submit" button. When I click it, the form-action works (directs to http://127.0.0.1:8000/your-name/ which is 404if that matters - my main problem is that I cant get the input field to show up)
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `form_class = NameForm`, and also the `get` and `post` methods.

You should read the [Handling forms with class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views) section of the the documentation as well.

Comment: @Lomtrur I have a same problem, can you upload the code somewhere? I got lost somewhere. thanks...